# php curl/xpath data based off < p> text information?

Tags: php, xpath

I know how to xpath and echo text off another website via tags like div id, class ,etc, using the below code. But, I don't know how to do it under more precise conditions, for example when trying to scrape and echo a bit of text that has no unique tag identifier like a div.
This below code spits out scraped data.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.nbcnews.com/business');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//div[@class='market']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces
}
```

In this below source code for an example, I want to pull the value "21,271.97". But there's no unique tag for this, no div id. Is it possible to pull this data by identifying a keyword in the < p> that never changes, for example "DJIA all time".

```
<p>DJIA All Time, Record-High Close: <font color="#0000FF">June 9, 
2017</font> 
(<font color="#FF0000"><b bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><font face="Verdana, Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">21,271.97</font></b></font>)</p>
```

Wondering if I could possibly replace this with something around the lines of $query = "//div[@class='market']";
$query = "//p['DJIA all time']";

Could this be possible?

I also wonder if using a loop with something like $query = "//p[='DJIA']";? 
could work, though I don't know how to use that exactly.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to have a play with an online XPath tester - I use https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

```
$query = "//p[contains(text(),'DJIA')]";
```

Although if you use the page your after, I've found that the value seems to be the first record for...

```
$query = "//span[contains(@class,'market_price')]";
```

But the idea is the same in both cases, using `contains(source,value)` will match a set of nodes.  In the first case the text() is the value of the node,the second looks for the specific class definition.

Comment: awesome, this is working. able to plug in different words and it's giving me the data, great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below `XPath` expression:

```
//p[contains(text(), "DJIA All Time")]//b/font
```

Considering provided link (http://www.nbcnews.com/business) you can get required text with

```
//span[text()="DJIA"]/following-sibling::span[@class="market_item market_price"]
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer, do you know how to make that work with the existing code I have? pretty new to php, trying to place it in correctly but having had any luck yet.